# how to create video from images using ffmpeg Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have used FFMPEG for generating video from images, but always it takes same FPS. How to change the FPS in generating video?

```
    cmd = new String[5];
                cmd[0] = "-f";
                cmd[1] = "image2";
                cmd[2] = "-i";
                cmd[3] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Photo Story/image%d.jpg";
                cmd[4] = PathVideo + "/"+ FileName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cmd = new String[7];
cmd[0] = "-f";
cmd[1] = "image2";
cmd[2] = "-framerate";
cmd[3] = "25"; // <-- replace with fps
cmd[4] = "-i";
cmd[5] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/PhotoStory/image%d.jpg";
cmd[6] = PathVideo + "/"+ FileName;
```

Replace `25` with the variable or value of framerate.

Comment: min FPS for video?? i used 4 FPS and got error Unable to find a suitable output format for '4'

Comment: Show the formatted command. That message indicates that ffmpeg is interpreting 4 as an output filename.

Comment: can you share code for genearte video from images with FPS = 4??

Comment: `ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 4 -i  "path/to/image%d.jpg" "/path/to/output.mp4"` <-- this is the command your code should generate.

Comment: cmd = new String[11];
    cmd[0] = "-f";
    cmd[1] = "image2";
    cmd[2] = "-framerate"; 
    cmd[3] = "1.0"; 
    cmd[4] = "-i";
    cmd[5] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Photo Story/image%d.jpg";
    cmd[6] = "-vf";
    cmd[7] = "fps=1";
    cmd[8] = "-pix_fmt";
    cmd[9] = "yuv420p";
    cmd[10] = PathVideo + "/"+ FileName;

Comment: You don't need the filter. If you're having an issue with the display of the last image, just duplicate that file and rename it to end the sequence.

Comment: video generated sucessfully but how can i add audio when generating video .  i used below code  cmd = new String[11];
    cmd[0] = "-f";
    cmd[1] = "image2";
    cmd[2] = "-framerate"; 
    cmd[3] = "3"; 
    cmd[4] = "-i";
    cmd[5] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Photo Story/image%d.jpg";
    cmd[6] = "-vf";
    cmd[7] = "fps=1";
    cmd[8] = "-pix_fmt";
    cmd[9] = "yuv420p";
    cmd[10] = PathVideo + "/"+ FileName;

Comment: Insert a `-i audio.mp3` and `-c:a copy` If the audio is longer than the video, also add `-shortest`

Comment: Error parsing options for input file /storage/emulated/0/Music/Lalla+Lalla+Lori_5974763.mp3.

Comment: cmd = new String[16];
    cmd[0] = "-f";
    cmd[1] = "image2";
    cmd[2] = "-framerate"; 
    cmd[3] = "3"; 
    cmd[4] = "-i";
    cmd[5] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Photo Story/image%d.jpg";
    cmd[6] = "-vf";   
    cmd[7] = "fps=1";
    cmd[8] = "-pix_fmt";
    cmd[9] = "yuv420p";
    cmd[10] = "-i";
    cmd[11] = AUDIOPATH;
    cmd[12] = "-c:a";
    cmd[13] = "copy";
    cmd[14] = "-shortest";
    cmd[15] = PathVideo + "/"+ FileName;

Comment: Option vf (set video filters) cannot be applied to input file /storage/emulated/0/Music/Lalla+Lalla+Lori_5974763.mp3 -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.

Comment: Thanx - Mulvya i got sollution cmd = new String[16];
    cmd[0] = "-f";
    cmd[1] = "image2";
    cmd[2] = "-framerate"; 
    cmd[3] = "3"; 
    cmd[4] = "-i";
    cmd[5] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Photo Story/image%d.jpg";  
    cmd[6] = "-i";
    cmd[7] = AUDIOPATH;
    cmd[8] = "-c:a";
    cmd[9] = "copy";
    cmd[10] = "-vf";   
    cmd[11] = "fps=1";
    cmd[12] = "-pix_fmt";
    cmd[13] = "yuv420p";   
    cmd[14] = "-shortest";
    cmd[15] = PathVideo + "/"+ FileName;

Comment: @ Mulvya - how to generate video in reverse oreder?

Comment: If your ffmpeg version is recent, you can use reverse filter i.e. `-vf fps=1,reverse`. But this will read entire sequence into memory.

Comment: reverse: Invalid argument

Comment: You've an old version of ffmpeg. You'll have to rename your images in reverse order.

Comment: i have 100 images in folder but i wants to use only first 50 images to generate video. what is command for that??

Comment: You'll have to insert `-t n` before `-i` where value of `n` is no. of required images / framerate

Comment: please send me link for latest ffmpeg lib

Comment: Don't work with Android, so don't know about getting latest lib.

Comment: How to cut video using ffmpeg??

Answer (score 1):

### Full ffmpag command for convert images to video

---

- I have used below library of ffmpag

  ```
  implementation 'com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-full-gpl:4.4'
  ```
- First write all images in one txt file

  ```
  val imageFileList = File(imagesFilePath)
  val txtFileWriterImages = imageFileList.bufferedWriter()

   // Write the list of image file paths to a temporary file and give as input
  images.forEach {
       txtFileWriterImages.write("file '$it'\n")
  }

  txtFileWriterImages.close()
  ```
- Command

  ```
  val command = arrayOf(
               "-f",
               "image2",
               "-r",
               fps.toString(), // set the output frame rate
               "-f",
               "concat",
               "-safe",
               "0",
               "-i",
               imageFileList.absolutePath,// where image file list is all images writes in one .txt file,
               "-i",
               watermarkPath, // add waternak in bottom of video if needed
               "-filter_complex",
               "[1:v]scale=$scale*0.05:-1,format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.75 [watermark]; [0:v][watermark]overlay=$x:$y[out]",
               "-map",
               "[out]",
               "-c:v",
               "libx264",
               "-b:v",
               "5M",
               "-r",
               "30",
               "-preset",
               "ultrafast",
               "-crf",
               "23",
               "-s",
               "1280x720", // video quality
               "-pix_fmt",
               "yuv420p",
               "-movflags",
               "faststart",
               "-threads",
               "auto", // Automatically set the number of threads
               finalVideoPath // path where store output video
           )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```java
cmd = new String[16];
cmd[0] = "-f";
cmd[1] = "image2";
cmd[2] = "-framerate"; 
cmd[3] = "3"; // <-- using framerate of 3 fps
cmd[4] = "-i";
cmd[5] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Photo Story/image%d.jpg";      
cmd[6] = "-i";
cmd[7] = AUDIOPATH;
cmd[8] = "-c:a";
cmd[9] = "copy";
cmd[10] = "-vf";            
cmd[11] = "fps=1";
cmd[12] = "-pix_fmt";
cmd[13] = "yuv420p";            
cmd[14] = "-shortest";
cmd[15] = PathVideo + "/"+ FileName;
```